# Is the mate-in-n problem of infinite chess with each color using traditional pieces plus one huygens decidable?

Tags: computability, undecidability, board-games

I noticed in a paper that the mate-in-n problem of chess, even played on an infinite board is decidable. [The mate-in-n problem of inﬁnite chess is decidable](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.5597v4.pdf)

I believe the paper assumes only **traditional chess** pieces are used.

What if one of the chess pieces is a **huygens**? (A huygens is a chess piece which jumps **prime numbers** of squares).

Is the mate-in-n problem of chess on an unbounded board with each color using traditional chess pieces plus at least **one huygens** also decidable?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57159/discussion-on-question-by-tomoka-kazuki-is-the-mate-in-n-problem-of-infinite-che).

Answer (score 2):

[Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) with a predicate for the primes [is probably undecidable](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266508733_Decidability_and_undecidability_of_theories_with_a_predicate_for_the_primes), so at least the technique used by your question's link should not easily generalize to allowing a huygens.

For example, although decidability of the special case I'm about to mention

would follow from there being only finitely many positive even integers that

are neither [prime gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) nor sums of two *distinct* primes, I don't see any way of

*proving* decidability of mate-in-ONE for king+huygens against a smothered king:

[image]

Comment: In your position, the white huygens must be on the same row/column as the black king, otherwise it's trivially decidable.

Comment: Yes. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I think that's a good answer, and I also like the composed position you created to illustrate it. I really appreciate the thought that you put into this.